# Pandas - Data Frame string value count

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I Need to know how many time a string appears in my dataframe, I used the follow sentence:

```
print(df['Mobile Register' == df.col1].shape[0])
```

But my problem is, I need to find all registers where contains Mobile Register, because in my data frame this string can be Mobile Register **1**, Mobile Register **2**, Mobile Register **3**, Mobile Register **n** ...

So I understand my command will not be used, therefore, what a need to do to find the count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don´t know it could be helpful or if it is the best solution, but I found what I want with the follow sentence

```
names = df.col1.tolist()
count=0
for colname in enumerate(names):
    print(colname[1])
    if ('Mobile Register' in str(colname[1])):
        count=count+1
```

Comment: names = df.col1.tolist() will show me all registers from col1,

Comment: I agree with you, I can delete this answer, I thought in this before read about series.str.contains():

Answer (score 1):

Use [`series.str.contains()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df.loc[df['col_name'].str.contains('Mobile Register',na=False)]
```

This will give you all the rows satisfying the condition.

*To find count of a specific column which meets this condition , use:*

```
df.loc[df['col_name'].str.contains('Mobile Register',na=False),'column_name'].count()
```

*If you need count of all columns satisfying this conditio*n:

```
df.loc[df['col_name'].str.contains('Mobile Register',na=False)].count()
```